# Not able to install TwitteR2Mongo Package in R

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install an R package for autonomous processing of Twitter data with the help of `TwitteR2Mongo`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘TwitteR2Mongo’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

package may not have been published to CRAN.  but it builds from github for me on 3.4.3.

try

`install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("ProjectTw/TwitteR2Mongo")`